# Replace a part of an AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replace

I need to replace a part of an AJAX response,I  have an ajax response on this form for example:

```
{"vals":["val1223","val1389","val1897","val1321"]}
```

I need to replace '**val1**' for each of these values and render them in italic form for example.

I tried like this but nothing changed on my display:

```
 var queryvar =$('#search').val();//value sent in AJAX query
display="";
display +="<ul>";

 //in response

 if(data.vals){
    $.each(data.vals, function(k,v){
       v = v.replace(queryvar, '<i>' +queryvar+ '</i>'); 
       display +='<li>' + v + '</li>';
    }); 
  }
display +="</ul>";
$('#results').html(display);
```

Comment: Where are you appending `display` to the DOM?

Comment: Related: [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/494035/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace `val1`, check [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and there is no need for regex here.

`v = v.replace(queryvar, '<i>' + queryvar + '</i>');`

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/3GShv/), thanks to @kmsdev

Comment: please elaborate what do you mean by "doesn't work" ? is there an error? what is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: I have the same result when I display the results,no part is displayed in italic.Also I want to remember that my query value is val1

Comment: It might be a CSS issue. did you check the HTML itself?

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

iTry this

```
 if(data.vals){
    var reg = new RegExp(queryvar,"i");
    $.each(data.vals, function(k,v){
       v = v.replace(reg, '<i>' +queryvar+ '</i>'); 
       display +='<li>' + v + '</li>';
    }); 
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahc9U/

Comment: There are anything in Console?

Comment: I understood why it doesn't work:my values are in capital letter:VAL1222,VAL1389....

Comment: Try now, I changed RegExp(queryvar,"g"); to RegExp(queryvar,"i");

Comment: Yes now it's ok thanks,the query values are in italic but always in lowercase,thanks a lot!!!!